# CMD can't normaly read 'C:\Program Files'

Tags: python, windows, cmd, directory

I have some problem with my WIndows CMD.
Some time I need to  open python file using CMD command. And I write: 'C:\Program Files\Python X.X\python.exe file.py' but have error: 'C:\Program' isn't system command (maybe not the same, I have another OS language).
With different methods I have different errors but can't open python file.
Examples:

[(Picture) translate: can't find 'C:\Program'...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1OWS.png)

[(Picture) another example when I trying to write python directory first and then start python file, but it can't find python file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqkrk.png)

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Start typing the path then press Tab for autocomplete that includes quotes.

Comment: flask doesn't belong in the system32 directory. Did you unpack it there? That's making a spaghetti mess of the system. flask should be installed using `pip install flask`, to install it and in its dependencies to Python's "site-packages" directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be 2 different problems here.

Windows does not recognise spaces in directory or file names on the command line, so you need to put the directory insied "" .
i.e. "C:\Program Files\Python 3.4\python.exe"

In your second picture, suggests that run.py does not exist in the current directory. Change Directory to where the run.py file is before running that command.

Comment: about second picture: run.py (it is on picture) is in current library, so please give me more details.
about first: ok, thanks.

Comment: I think, from your picture that your run.py file is in c:\windows\system32\flask\scripts.  In which case you need to add that path so python known where to find it. i.e. 'python c:\windows\system32\flask\scripts\run.py'

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to the directory where your python file is located ... like:

```
cd "c:\users\someone\documents\..."
```

On your pictures you are trying to run python file located in system32 folder but i guess it is not located there so move where the file is with that cd command

Then as Martin says the problem with path of python.exe is the space between words. To solve put the path into quotation marks.
But u can add python to system path and insted of writing full path u can write only

```
 python file.py
```

How to add python to path see here https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path

Comment: Thanks, if work. I don't want to ue system path because I using different python versions for different projects.